# Understanding inf$_zF(z)$

Tags: notation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to understand the proof of "The set if minima of F is convex where F is a convex function)

The proof starts with considering  $ F(x) = F(y) = \inf_z F(z) $ and then shows the contradiction of $ F(tx + (1-t)y) \le tF(x) + (1-t)F(y) = \inf_zF(z) $ for  all $ t \in  (0,1) $

I not getting the idea of $\inf_zF(z)$ component of this proof. Can you share insight please.

Comment: Do you know the definition of infinum?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yes i do.

Comment: $\inf_Z F(z)$ denotes the infimum of the set $\{ F(z) : z \in \mathrm{Domain \ of } F\}$

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easier to show that the level sets are convex.

Let $L_\alpha = \{z | F(z) \le \alpha \}$. If $z_1,z_2 \in L_\alpha$, then
$f(\lambda z_1+(1-\lambda) z_2) \le \lambda_1 F(z_1)+ (1-\lambda) F(z_2) \le \alpha$ and so $L_\alpha$ is convex.

Now let $\alpha = \inf_z F(z)$. Then $L_\alpha$ is convex.
(Note that $L_\alpha$ may be empty, for example, let $F(z) = e^z$, then there is
no minimum, but $\inf_z F(z) = 0$.)